# Update all values in Pandas Dataframe column A, with columns B's value BUT only if the value in B is non zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My previous code update all values in B with the values in A, where B was zero

```
dft = pd.DataFrame(
                    np.array([
                                ['Unknown', 0], ['Unknown', 'CORP'], ['Unknown', 'GOVT'], ['Unknown', 0]
                            ]), columns=['A', 'B']
                  )
print(dft)
mask = dft['B'] == '0'
dft.loc[mask, 'B'] = dft['A']

         A     B
0  Unknown     0
1  Unknown  CORP
2  Unknown  GOVT
3  Unknown     0

         A        B
0  Unknown  Unknown
1  Unknown     CORP
2  Unknown     GOVT
3  Unknown  Unknown
```

But I would like to do the inverse and update A with all values in B which are non-zero. I can update the whole of A with B but I'd like to preserve the existing values in A as replacing with a zero is not helpful

Desired result:

```
         A     B
0  Unknown     0
1  CORP     CORP
2  GOVT     GOVT
3  Unknown     0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html). To replace columns:

```
dft = dft.where(dft['B'] == '0', dft.B, axis=0)
print (dft)
         A     B
0  Unknown     0
1     CORP  CORP
2     GOVT  GOVT
3  Unknown     0
```

But, to replace only column `A`:

```
dft['A'] = dft['A'].where(dft['B'] == '0', dft.B)
#dft.loc[dft['B'] !='0','A'] = dft['B']

print (dft)
         A     B
0  Unknown     0
1     CORP  CORP
2     GOVT  GOVT
3  Unknown     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be,

```
df.loc[df.B!='0','A']=df['B']
```

O/P:

```
         A     B
0  Unknown     0
1     CORP  CORP
2     GOVT  GOVT
3  Unknown     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.where`

```
df['A'] = np.where(df['B']!=0, df['B'], df['A'])
```